# Integrate CodeQL in commercial project without github

Tags: python, github, codeql

I have been using CodeQL for some private projects and now I'd like to use it for a project at work unfortunately we can not use github there.

How can we run CodeQL compliant to the GitHub CodeQL Terms and Conditions? Is it sufficient to pay for GitHub Enterprise and just use CodeQL as I did it in my private projects?

Thank you!

Comment: Not only is this a non-programming question (and therefore not really suited to StackOverflow) - it is also a legal question, and anyone who isn't a lawyer would be ill-advised to respond with anything that will directly address your question.

Answer (score 0):

I see two viable options:

1. Consult a lawyer who has some expertise in the field of software licenses.
2. Follow their advice.

**or**

1. As suggested in the last sentence of the GitHub CodeQL Terms and Conditions, ask the folks at https://support.github.com/contact.
2. Follow their advice.

Either way, you absolutely, positively want an authoritative statement on the matter, not just conjectural advice from a community of programmers.